# Backpack Laravel select2_from_ajax field returns results, but I can't select any

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I'm implementing a 'select2_from_ajax' field using Backpack for Laravel.

I've implemented this in other places and it works correctly. But for some reason when implementing it this time it will not let me select any of the options and doesn't show the highlight when mousing over the options. It lists out the options correctly, I just can't select any of them.

The only thing I can think of is that the relationship it's trying to reference doesn't have a primary 'id' field in the database, but I'm not sure why that would affect this.

I have implemented both the index and show routes.

Comment: please share the code in your crud controller and the route you use, make sure the route in your custom.php not api.php

Comment: @OMR - Thanks. This seemed to be a data structure issue.  I changed the primary key column name from 'x' to 'id' and that seemed to resolve the issue. I'm not sure if this is a limitation of Backpack for Laravel or if I had something configured incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that the relationship field's primary key was not 'id' it was setup with a different column name.

I reworked the data structure so the foreign key referenced was pointing to a column labeled 'id'.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution James. I'm sure it'll help _someone someday_ 